# 3d plotting with large z axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

So I am trying to create a 3d plot from a simple 2d gaussian-like line profiles. The two-d plot is fine, but I am hoping to implement a z axis which will contain many of these 2d profiles. Is it possible to have multiple 2d plots stacked together into a wireframe 3d plot?

I have chosen point 5000 in the variable data1b in order to get one 2d plot to work.
data1bs shape is (71676, 64)
spatial is just (64)

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(spatial, data1b[5000])
plt.xlabel('Wavelength (Angstroms)', fontsize=18)
```

Is it possible to have say 1000 of these 2d plots inplemented into a wireframe?
Below is one of my attempts

```
ax1a = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax1a.plot_wireframe(data1b[50000:51000], xaxis1[50000:51000], yaxis1[50000:51000)
```

I am not sure as to the format of each array for 3d implementation.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: First guess: doable, you can't actually see all that data on a screen so you will probably be subsetting it somehow, I can't tell what you're aiming for without dummy data (small sets please!). Are any of the [matplotlib gallery 3D examples](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/wire3d_demo.html) simple versions of what you need?

Comment: That is OK, it is just to get the general form of the data and be able to show this in a 3d plot. I think a wireframe will work, but the 3d examples in matplotlib gallery don't really go into the required shape of each axis array, which is where i'm finding it hard to program. This is a link to a 64 x 64 array of gaussian like profiles: https://maynoothuniversity-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/eoin_cahill_mumail_ie/EXAlAdvJX2lPmdYEqkI9OSUBIrhQ5ompY7ZgJaRH-Jy6dA?e=chML3L Thanks

Comment: https://maynoothuniversity-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/eoin_cahill_mumail_ie/EXAlAdvJX2lPmdYEqkI9OSUBIrhQ5ompY7ZgJaRH-Jy6dA?e=MohgOR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So answer is that the X and Y arrays are just positional, and the Z array is the dataset to be shown. They do have to be square arrays unfortunately, so in my case the arrays are 64 x 64, but this could be increased by adding more noise to the spatial array.